# move the lines in the tables cell up and down

Tags: tables

Is it possible to move the lines up and down in the cell to look  similar as the line in the first and second cells?

[image]

**latex code:**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|} 

\hline
status & indication  \\
\hline
201 & The route and direction were successful  updated.  \\
\hline
230 & The route and direction are being detected.  \\
\hline
202 & \pbox{30cm}{Deletion of the route, direction and other related data from the bus \\ and algorithm tables in case they were detected by the algorithm.}  \\
\hline
203 & \pbox{30cm}{Deletion of the route, direction and other related data from the bus \\and algorithm tables in case they were detected by the WiFi AP.}  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
 \caption{The indication of the status values.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that `pbox` (here) is not wanted  and even if it's wanted, not with `30cm`.

Use a `p` columntype (which uses a `\parbox` effectively!)

In my point of view the numbers should be right aligned, but that's a personal opinion.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|p{10cm}|} 

\hline
status & indication  \\
\hline
201 & The route and direction were successful  updated.  \\
\hline
230 & The route and direction are being detected.  \\
\hline
202 & Deletion of the route, direction and other related data from the bus and algorithm tables in case they were detected by the algorithm.  \\
\hline
203 & Deletion of the route, direction and other related data from the bus and algorithm tables in case they were detected by the WiFi AP.  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
 \caption{The indication of the status values.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]